# Create a file and write struct with data member and the file created is empty

Tags: c

I create a program that prompts the user to choose an option, like below:

1. create a file and name the file.
2. add component in the file
3. display the item in the file
4. exit program

So my problem is the file is created and exists in my directory, but it is empty, so where did I miss something? plus can you check whether the 2 and 3 option program are OK?

Here my program:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main() { 
    int num, name;
    
start:
        
    printf("\n1. Create a file.");
    printf("\n2. Add a component to the list.");
    printf("\n3. Display the current list of component.");
    printf("\n4. Exit program.");
    printf("\n\nChoose either these four menu = ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    fflush(stdin);

    switch (num) {
      case 1:
        printf("\n\nPlease enter file name: ");
        scanf("%d", &name);
        FILE *pf = NULL;
        char username[250];
        char userfile[255];
        
        printf("username: ");
        scanf("%s", username);
        sprintf(userfile, "%s.txt", username);
        fflush(stdin);
        goto start;
        break;

      case 2:
        pf = fopen(userfile, "w");
        if (!pf) {
            fprintf(stderr, "File opening failed!\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        struct date {
            int day;
            int month;
            int year;
        };
        struct details {
            char name[20];
            int price;
            int code;
            int qty;
            struct date mfg;
        };
        struct details item[50];
        int n, i;
        
        printf("Enter number of items:");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        fflush(stdin);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Item name: \n");
            scanf("%s", item[i].name);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Item code: \n");
            scanf("%d", &item[i].code);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Quantity: \n");
            scanf("%d", &item[i].qty);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("price: \n");
            scanf("%d",  &item[i].price);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Manufacturing date(dd-mm-yyyy): \n");
            scanf("%d-%d-%d", &item[i].mfg.day,
                  &item[i].mfg.month, &item[i].mfg.year);
        }
        fclose(pf);
        goto start;
        break;
        
      case 3:
        pf = fopen(userfile, "r");
        if (!userfile) {
            fprintf(stderr, "File opening failed!\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        {
            printf("             *****  INVENTORY ***** \n");
            printf("------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("S.N.|    NAME           |   CODE   |  QUANTITY |  PRICE | MFG.DATE \n");
            printf("-------------------------------------------------------- ---------\n");
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                fprintf("%d     %-15s        %-d          %-5d     %-5d %d/%d/%d \n",
                        i + 1, item[i].name, item[i].code, item[i].qty,
                        item[i].price, item[i].mfg.day, item[i].mfg.month,
                        item[i].mfg.year);
            printf("------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        }
        fclose(pf);
        goto start;
        break;
    
      case 4:
        printf("Exit Program, Thank You, Sayonara");
        break; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (!userfile) {` -> `if (!pf) {` It also looks like you open the file for reading and then try to write to it. This is really a spaghetti goto mess.

Comment: regarding: `fflush(stdin);`  this is specifically called out in the C standard as undefined behavior

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", item[i].name);`  with `%s`, always include a MAX WIDTH modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input field.  1 less because `%s` always appends a NUL byte to the input

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the test `if (!userfile)` is incorrect: you should test `if (!pf)` instead
- you open the file for reading, you should open it for writing with `"w"`, or possibly for appending with `"a"`.
- you never write to the file. You should use `fprintf(pf, ...)` instead of `printf`.
- the arrays `userfile`, `item` and variables `i` and `n` are local inside the `switch` statement: their contents go out of scope when you go to the `start` label outside de `switch` statement. Move all these definitions outside the `switch` statement.
- `fflush(stdin);` has undefined behavior. You can consume (*flush*) the rest of the input line with: `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') continue;` You can define a function `flush()` that does it.

Comment: ok thanks for the info, may i know , i should change the fprint(pf,....) at where? i assume at the  statement case 2 right?

Comment: @MuhammadRahimy: it unclear when you are supposed to write to the file. Option 1 gets the username, 2 creates the file and read items, 3 prints the items from the local array and 4 exits.

Comment: I use the ffprint() , they now write into the text file. But the problem is, it not show in the screen while put the input . So i can double the output for the screen and write to the text file? Example fprint() and below printf()?